Databricks CLI and Azure CLI -
Currently deploying the Databricks worksapce using Azure CLI,
function Create-Databricks {
    param (
        [string] $rgName,
        [string] $dbName
    )
    
    az databricks workspace create --resource-group $rgName --name $dbName --location westeurope --output none

}

But I would like to enable this worksapace for Unity Catalog and also delpoy 1 external storage account.
how can I do this?

Instead of using Databricks CLI, a better approach is to use Terraform. There are lot of examples available here https://github.com/databricks/terraform-databricks-examples/tree/main/examples

@GaneshChandrasekaran well, I do have a very giant script of terraform, but in this case Im limited to these two languages

In your use case, Databricks CLI will work better as it's custom-developed for their platform.
Please make sure you have the latest version of Databricks CLI >= v0.220.0
https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/cli/install.html
databricks workspace-bindings update-bindings storage-credential <my-storage-credential> \
--json '{
  "add": [{"workspace_id": <workspace-id>}...],
}' --profile <profile-name>

For more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/connect/unity-catalog/storage-credentials#cli

my Use case will requrire to use both Azure CLI and Databricks CLI. Using the YAML pipelines
